# Что означает такая форма вызова метода?

Tags: c#

Есть строка в коде:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                        (obj, certificate, chain, errors) => true
```

Не понимаю смысл строки (пытаюсь разобрать чужой код). Если (obj, certificate, chain, errors) - параметры метода, то почему перед ними знак равенства? И что значит "=> true" после них?

Comment: При этом, я не нашел в текущем файле упоминаний об obj, certificate, chain, errors, но не ругается студия как на неопределенные переменные. Может глобальные, иначе еще одна странность.

Comment: вообще-то знак => - это лямбда выражение, почитайте про него, и поймете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private bool MyMethod(TypeOfObj obj, TypeOfCertificate certificate, TypeOfChain chain, TypeOfErrors errors)
{
   return true;
}

...
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = MyMethod;
```

Answer (score 4):

Свойство [`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) имеет тип [делегата `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx)

Знак равенства здесь потому что мы записываем в это свойство значение. В качестве значения здесь выступает анонимная функция `(obj, certificate, chain, errors) => true`, которая при любых параметрах возвращает значение true.

Этот код можно развернуть примерно так (на самом деле его компилятор и разворачивает, но даёт методу специальное имя, к которому мы не имеем доступа):

```
bool someRemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
    object sender,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
    = someRemoteCertificateValidationCallback;
```